# Creating an empty Shield UI ASP.NET chart on a web page

Tags: asp.net, shieldui

I have a problem creating a Shield UI ASP.NET Chart on my web page. What I need is to have the control with not data, but yet visible on the page.
I have the reference to the control at the beginning:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="Shield.Web.UI" Namespace="Shield.Web.UI" TagPrefix="shield" %>
```

And here is the complete code actually:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm2.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.WebForm2" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="Shield.Web.UI" Namespace="Shield.Web.UI" TagPrefix="shield" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

<div id="chart" style="width: 390px; height: 290px; left: 5px; top:5px; margin: auto; position:inherit;">
                <shield:ShieldChart ID="ShieldChart1" runat="server" Width="320px" Height="330px"
                    OnTakeDataSource="ShieldChart1_TakeDataSource">
                    <DataSeries>

                    </DataSeries>
                </shield:ShieldChart>
            </div>        
    </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dragging and dropping the control in the VS doesn’t do all the work needed to show the control when page is launched. What you need is to add some more lines of code, and namely:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="shield-chart.1.2.2-Trial/shield-chart.1.2.2-Trial/css/shield-chart.min.css" />
<script src="shield-chart.1.2.2-Trial/shield-chart.1.2.2-Trial/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript">        //</script>
<script src="shield-chart.1.2.2-Trial/shield-chart.1.2.2-Trial/js/shield-chart.all.min.js" type="text/javascript">        //</script>
```

These are the actual references to the runtime components you need to use the control in your web application.